# c++ deallocate 2d int array error

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I get very frustrating error in following piece of code. Thats my array.

```
int **tab2 = new int*[3];
```

I allocate this like it.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tab2[i] = new int[3];
    tab2[i][0] = 40;
    tab2[i][1] = 10;
    tab2[i][2] = 100;
}
```

Then after using it i want to destroy it.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    delete [] tab2[i];
}
delete [] tab2;
```

And this causes core dump every single time. I tried many different ways to destroy it and every time get this error. What im making wrong here ?

Comment: everything is wrong in your code. what was the intention?

Comment: ofcourse its only a scratch to illustrate what i want to do. I want to get information on how to destroy it correct way as i said.

Comment: your allocation is wrong in the first place.

Comment: I do not understand why people keep on downvoting good question. Though he has done some technical mistake, but SO is not only for `experts`. @10101101 Your question is good. +1 for it.

Comment: tab2 is sized for 3 and then you put 10 things in it.

Comment: Yes harshness should rise with experience of OP.  Why rip into new people to the site?

Comment: but wait the first dimension size is dynamic right - so i thought that it can have any size, like 10, and 3 is for nd dimension. Am i right ? Im newbie in c++.

Comment: No, it's not.  That's a problem....

Comment: @10101101, think for a bit, where would that space come from?

Comment: @pranitkothari It is perfectly fine to down-vote poor questions. That is what is supposed to happen. What is not supposed to happen is for people to *up*-vote poor questions.

Comment: what's a poor question is sort of in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
int **tab2 = new int*[3];
```

does not do what you think it does.

You want an array that will contain TEN (10) pointers, each to an array of THREE ints.

`new int*[3]` is an array that contain THREE pointers.

[What you want is this (live at coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f98b09a2c77b2bc7):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  int **tab2 = new int*[10];

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tab2[i] = new int[3];
    tab2[i][0] = 40;
    tab2[i][1] = 10;
    tab2[i][2] = 100;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    delete [] tab2[i];
  }
  delete [] tab2;

}
```

Comment: @Jim :: there is a "live at coliru" link in the answer and, yes, it runs... (in contrast with the `new int*[3]`, that aborts with a backtrace! :D)

Comment: But i was wondering just now. When we have this "= new int*[10];", it means 10 rows with any number of cols. But can we declare it so it will be any number of rows with e.g. 10 number of cols ? From Rook's answer i know that vectors support it. But i wonder is it possible with traditional arrays ?

Comment: Nope, just with vectors.

Comment: Actually, to be more accurate, `new int*[10]` does **not** mean _"10 rows with any number of cols"_; it means "a pointer to the first element of an array of 10 pointers to int" -- on each of those "ten pointers to int" you subsequently stored "a pointer to the first element of an array of 3 ints" (but it could be any number of "columns"). when you write `tab2[x][y]` you are actually saying "give me the `x`th element of tab2; it's a pointer to an array of ints; now give me the `y`th element of the array pointed by this last pointer." Got it? :D

Comment: Sure :) But hey, they did some magic with vectors ? Correct me if Im wrong here, but i belive that vectors are actually traditional arrays, when it comes to their implementation. So if thats true, it means there is a way, right ? :) If yes, interesting how complicated it is...

Comment: @10101101: the "magic" done with `<vector>` is that `std::vector` is class, that encapsulates things like the access via `operator[]`, `begin()`, `end()`, and has a well-defined interface ([read the documentation here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).

Answer (score 2):

With

```
int **tab2 = new int*[3];
```

you allocate an array of pointers of size 3. But than with

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tab2[i] = new int[3];
    //...
}
```

you access it with up to index `9`. That will surely go wrong. 
The deletion process looks fine to me. To fix it, you should allocate an array of pointers with size `10`instead of `3`, e.g.

```
int **tab2 = new int*[10];
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you're trying to do is to create an N by M array, where N is known at runtime and M is fixed (in this case, 3).

Why not just do this?

```
{
    std::array<int, 3> defaults = {{ 40, 10, 100 }};
    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> thing(10, defaults);
}
```

The vector, `thing` is automatically deallocated when it goes out of scope, and its size can be set at runtime. You still access the structure in the same way:

```
thing[1][2] = 3
```

Manual memory management can be easily avoided by using standard containers and smart pointers. Doing so will keep you code cleaner, and have fewer opportunities for dangling pointers and memory leaks.

Comment: @10101101, this the correct way to go. C++ allows deterministic lifetimes of objects. Have a look at smart pointers such as `unique_ptr` rather than raw pointers.

Comment: @Rook, don't you need a space between the two right bracket thingies? Or did they fix that?

Comment: @Jim if you're using a C++ compiler recent enough to understand `std::array`, it should also be clever enough to differentiate `>>` as part of a template declaration from the right-shift operator. I think its part of the standard now.

Comment: It looks like it is part of the C++ 11 standard now, but not necessarily for any compiler before that.

Comment: Sorry for so long, but i wasn't at home. Thanks for some different solution, I think i will need those also in future. Again, THX for taking time for noob like me.